# canopy python turtle on mac 64bit

Tags: python, macos, turtle-graphics, canopy

**IMPORTANT** i did not notice that there were two different places where i had to change the settings from Qt4 to SVG. I changed them both and the problem regarding the "no Turtle found" was solved. I need to thank Jonathan March, who turned me in the right direction with the link he suggested.

**PROBLEM SOVED!!**

I'm using Canopy 1.3.0.1715 (32bit) on a MacBook Pro 64bit OS 10.9.2.

When i try to use

```
from turtle import Turtle
```

Canopy says

```
name 'Turtle' is not defined
```

Here is my code, named draw.py (i want to draw a square):

```
from turtle import Turtle
t = Turtle()
def drawsquare(t, x, y, side):
    t.up()
    t.goto(x,y)
    t.setheading(270)
    t.down()
    for count in range(4):
        t.forward(side)
        t.left(90)
```

I also created a file turtle.cfg like this

```
width = 300
height = 200
using_IDLE = True
colormode = 255
```

Please be as simple as you can, i just recently started using Python. Thanks everyone.

Comment: could you explain what your Turtle here is?

Comment: could you try t = turtle() instead of the capital T

Comment: do you have a file named "turtle.py" in the same folder where you're running this code?

Comment: as the book from which i am learning said (Fundamentals of Python: first programs) i created a file turtle.cfg (read above)

Comment: if i try t = turtle() Canopy still says `name 'Turtle' is not defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`from turtle import Turtle`

works for me on Canopy-32 bit on Mac64 (running in the Canopy python shell).

First thing to check: did you name some file `turtle.py`? If so, rename the file, delete the file turtle.pyc in the same directory if it exists, and try again. (If you name your file turtle.py, then python has no way to find the standard turtle module.)

Otherwise:

Where are you running this? In the Canopy python (ipython) shell?
Or did you start up Python some other way?

Wherever it is, what do you see when you type this?:

```
import sys, turtle
print sys.prefix
print turtle.__file__
```

Also, while this should not account for your import failure, be sure to read and follow the following:
https://support.enthought.com/entries/21793229-Using-Tkinter-Turtle-in-Canopy-s-IPython-panel

Comment: `/Users/mazzalex02/Library/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User` and `/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.3.0.1715.macosx-x86/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/turtle.pyc`

Comment: I checked the link. And solved the problem. Thank you very much. Read above to know what i did.